# Binding treeview with a Category object containing a list of childnode objects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

Showing the categories is no problem, but I can't get it to show the objects that should be inside the categories. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

XAML- Datatemplates.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Component">

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>

</DataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Category"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Component}">

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>

</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

XAML: Treeview

```
<telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="treeview" IsDragDropEnabled="True" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,10" Width="190" 
                     IsManipulationEnabled="True"
                     IsExpandOnSingleClickEnabled="True"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Category}" />
```

C#: The categoryclass containing childobjects for the treeview.(Generated from databasemodel)

```
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.MethodComponent = new HashSet<MethodComponent>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MethodComponent> MethodComponent { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

}

C# Getting the data:

```
    public List<Category> Get_Categories()
    {

        using (var context = new ProcessDatabaseEntities())
        {
           return context.Category.ToList();
        }
    }
```

C# binding the data:

```
treeview.ItemsSource = d.Get_Categories();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set **`ItemsSource`** on **`HierarchicalDataTemplate`** to **`MethodComponent`** to populate parent node with child collection.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Category"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Component}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding MethodComponent}">    

     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>    

</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Where have you populated `MethodComponent` collection and does `MethodComponent` class have property Name?

Comment: I guess it populates when I run the Get_Categories() method, since Methodcomponents have reference to category in the database.

Comment: Check by placing breakpoints it contains come objects. Also, does `MethodComponent` class have any property called `Name`?

Comment: I tried this: var item = d.Get_Categories();
         string name = item.First().MethodComponent.First().Name; and it gave me an error. So I guess my list is not filling? A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException'

Comment: Yes, so tried to resolve that issue. Seems issue in your entity fetching logic. Once it gets resolved above code will work fine.

Comment: Thank you. You dont happen to know how to solve the fetching error?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that expertise in `Entity Framework`. Try to post the code in another question here at SO with some details, someone here will help you out for sure.